# \newpage inside of \newtheorem

Tags: page-breaking, theorems

Ηow to enter `\newpage` in the environment so that each exercise is contained in its own page.

```
\newtheorem{exercise}{ \color{magenta} \Large \bfseries }[chapter]
```

Something seemingly simple but troubling enough time now without any result

I would prefer `\newtheorem` . And this because I have already thousands of exercises and just want each one on a separate page so that I can make handwritten corrections

Comment: You can use the package `xpatch` with `\xpretocmd{\exercise}{\clearpage}{}{}`

Comment: BTW: Why do you set the size etc. as argument?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel the `xpatch...` did not work for me. For your second comment I do not understand how to do this

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I guess I figured something wrong ... sorry my english not help me ... you mean about `\Large`?

Comment: I had the same problem with this language ;-). I provided an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a command before the exercise environment is executed, you can use the package `xpatch` which provides the command `\xpretocmd`:

Here an example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[chapter]

\xpretocmd{\exercise}{\clearpage}{}{}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
\kant
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
\kant
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
\kant
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

I don't know your package for theorems. A small list is:

- `amsthm`
- `ntheorem`
- `thmtools`

e.g. with `ntheorem` you can set the font by: `\theorembodyfont{}` or `\theoremheaderfont`

Comment: Sorry should Ι have mentioned  from the outset. I would prefer `\newtheorem` . And this because I have already thousands of exercises and just want each one on a separate page so that I can make handwritten corrections

Comment: @karathan: I used the command `\newtheorem`. What's the matter?

Comment: ok works very well ... after the first test. I thought that I will have a problem but everything is okay Thank you very much :)